# What do I need to learn actionscript 3 under linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, adobe-flash, actionscript-3

I'm am aspiring to learn ActionScript 3, but I am running linux and I wonder what I need to be able to write flash programs and test them on linux. Also, I'm looking for a free solution, if it exists..

btw: I'm running ubuntu 10.04

Comment: The best development tools are for Windows, you will have a lot of trouble to find a good IDE for linux.

Comment: @M28 rather broad statement there, do you even use linux for dev? If you did you wouldn't be making comments like that... ever hear of Eclipse or any of its derivatives(glory of Open Source software) for c++ or other languages? Put the fanboy tended comments aside and try to help...

Comment: I use FlashDevelop, and I test it in Ubuntu, I really don't like the linux environment for flash development, just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionScript is just JavaScript with some addons for Flash, so a good start is to learn JavaScript.  Our friends at [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) have proferred [some of the best resources for learning JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript).

There is one open source Flash/ActionScript IDE that runs on Linux that I could find:  [Open Dialect](http://osflash.org/projects/opendialect).  There are also two other Linux IDEs that output Flash SWF files, but do not use ActionScript:  [OpenLazlo](http://www.openlaszlo.com/) and [haXe](http://haxe.org/).  There is also an open source ActionScript/Flash IDE that only works on Windows called [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/).  I fear none of them will support all the features of the costly Flash development tools provided by Adobe, however.  They do offer 30 day free trials, but none of their development products run on Linux that I'm aware of (although they might be supported by [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/)).

There are two open source Flash plugin projects:  [Gnash](http://gnashdev.org/) and [Lightspark](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lightspark/).  Only the latter supports ActionScript 3.  Of course, the official [Flash Player for Linux](http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer) from Adobe is available at no charge as well.

The [osflash project](http://osflash.org/) has lots of information on Flash development with open source tools.  Finally, Stack Overflow also offers [some resources regarding learning ActionScript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168586/where-to-learn-actionscript-3-0).  Good luck!

Comment: Outstanding answer! I think I have a really good starting point here with Open Dialect and Stack Overflow's resources regarding learning ActionScript3 (I'm already very familiar with javascript). Thanks! (or should I say, upvote and accept answer)